# Can you use .NET without interfacing with COM?

Tags: .net, com, vb6

I've been reading up on Component Object Model and, while I'm confused why it's needed, I have a question regarding it.  From my undertanding, it's used to create interoperability between different languages, so my VB.NET program can communicate with my VC++ program.  Is there any other benefit to this?  If my application is only vb.net communicating with a vb.net architecture, is there a need to include COM in my application?  Do I have the option to not use COM?

Awhile back I read something on a website(i will search for the source) saying COM should only be used with vb6 and should not be included with your .NET applications, is this true?  Since COM is clearly made compatible with .NET technoligies, would including it my project 'dull' it down if there's better substitutes out there?

Comment: Kinda vague.  You can of course always interop with another program through a socket or a named pipe.  Your browser just did.

Comment: COM is for interop. That's all. You don't need it between .NET langs.